# Haskell - Given two integers, find all sublists

Tags: list, haskell, sublist

I am very new to Haskell and have searched high and low for help with this but I can't seem to be able to get it to work. **This is a homework assignment** but any help/pointers would be appreciated!

If I have 2 integers i and j, I need to find all sub-lists of [i,...,j], [more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRjl8.png). I can not use helper functions other than built-in functions.

I have a way to find all sub-lists of a given list(maybe not the best way):

```
myList x =
   if x==[]
      then [[]]
      else (myList (tail x))
      ++ (map
         (\a -> (head x):a)
         (myList (tail x))
         )
```

and I know how to change 2 integers into a list but for the life of me, I can not do both in the same function.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Maybe break up the problem into easily solvable cases. What are the sublists of `[i..j]` when `i>j`? What are the sublists of `[i..j]` when `i==j`? If you have all sublists of `[i+1..j]`, how would you obtain all sublists of `[i..j]` from those?

Comment: Instead of trying to change 2 integers into a list and then call `myList` with that list as arguments, you could change `myList` to take 2 integers and keep using those 2 integers while recursing. What is the value of `myList a b` if `a > b`? If `a <= b` how would you call `myList c d` in such a way that you recurse and eventually hit the base case?

Comment: `head (list i j) == i {IF i <= j ; error otherwise}`. `tail (list i j) = (list (i+1) j) {IF i <= j ; error otherwise}`. `(list i j) == []` <==> `i > j`.